# Current version of pytesseract produces wrong string

Tags: tesseract, python-tesseract

Image that I am processing (http://kkn.net/n6tr/eeflnn.png)

And I get EEELNN, not EEFLNN.

This seemed to work better in a previous version - although I am challenged to figure out how to get back to that version.  Was hoping it would be fixed in a newer version, but haven't seen that happen yet.

```
img = cv.imread ('eeflnn.png')
test = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, config="--psm 13")
print (test)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the information.  I tried the different psm modes and found that 6 works better than 13.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).